# Why can an instance method to be called like a static method in Rust?

Tags: rust

I've learned 2 ways to call methods in Rust.

The first way is called *static methods*, which does not require an instance and can be called directly using a struct.

The second way is called *instance methods*, which requires an object instance to call it.

And the difference between the two methods is whether the first argument is `self`.

example:

```
struct User {
    name: String,
}


impl User {
    //static method
    fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        User { name }
    }
    //instance method
    fn get_name(&self) -> String {
        self.name
    }
}
```

But I found some method can be called like this:

```
use chrono::Local;
use chrono::TimeZone;
fn main() {
    let time = Local.with_ymd_and_hms(2024, 1, 26, 15, 0, 0).unwrap();
    println!("{}", time.format("%F %T"));
}
```

I don't understand. `with_ymd_and_hms` is defined in `TimeZone` like this:

```
    fn with_ymd_and_hms(
        &self,
        year: i32,
        month: u32,
        day: u32,
        hour: u32,
        min: u32,
        sec: u32,
    ) -> LocalResult<DateTime<Self>> {
```

It should be an *instance method*. But why can it be called like `Local.with_ymd_and_hms`?

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: slight bit on terminology: Usually we refer to "static methods" as associated functions in Rust, methods always take `self` in some form as a receiver.

Comment: Notice that you called the method with `.` instead of `::`

Comment: The concepts in Rust don't map perfectly onto Object Oriented ones, Rust is not an Object Oriented language. If you're learning Rust you can squint and think "ok traits are like interfaces and structs are like classes" and it's kinda sorta close enough to carry you for awhile but it isn't really true at all, and this is one instance of divergence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at the [definition](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/src/chrono/offset/local/mod.rs.html#115) of `chrono::offset::Local`:

```rust
struct Local;
```

As you can see, `Local` is a [*unit-like struct*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#unit-like-structs-without-any-fields),
that doesn't have a struct body.

Rust allows you to use the name of these structs not just as a *type*, but
also implicitly as *value*.

`Local.with_ymd_and_hms` calls the instance method `with_ymd_and_hms`
on a **value** of type `Local`, which is an instance of this zero sized type that's implicitly constructed here.

You could instead write `Local{}.with_ymd_and_hms`, which has the same semantics. But as a special case, Rust allows the omission of the constructor braces for unit-like structs.

Comment: I think that once upon a time I read that for each unit struct, the compiler actually generates a const instance with the same name, so you'd have in effect `const Local: Local = Local`. Cannot find a source for this though.